# JavaEE 6 - EJB - Using an ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, ejb, executorservice

The EJB specification prohibits the manual management of threads. One must use an injected `ExecutorService`, which uses threads managed by the container.
This is valid starting from JavaEE 7.
What if I'm on JavaEE 6 (and EJB 2) and I'm not allowed to use external libraries?

The usecase is processing a big `ResultSet` row by row, and for each one perform a task which might be long running.

Comment: you can use @Asynchronous and try to mimic same behavior.

Comment: @techtrainer EJB 2.* does not offer any kind of annotation whatsoever. So no Asyncronous

Comment: can you cross check because jee6 has this annotation https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkkqg.html#gkicm

Comment: @LppEdd, you definitely have versions mixed up. JEE6 = EJB3.1.

Comment: @user3714601 I'm on spec 2.0 and cannot upgrade it. Even if I could upgrade to 3.0 (WebLogic 10.3.6 goes up to 3.0), I can't.